# Using button in tkinter, pass a certain variable to the rest of code and close the window

Tags: python, tkinter

I wish to create a window with few buttons where by clicking on each button a specific database is selected and certain codes executed which are represented with "print" function of the variable DB (last line).That is why, to answer to the first suggested answer, I cannot move the location of this print command.

The code:

```
from tkinter import *
def selDB (x):
    DB = None
    if x==1:
        DB = 'database001'
    else:
        DB= 'database002'
    root.destroy()
    print(DB)
    return DB

root= Tk()
button_1 = Button(root, text='database 1', command=lambda :selDB(1)) .pack()
button_2=  Button(root, text='database 2', command=lambda :selDB(2)) .pack()
root.mainloop() 

print('database is:',selDB)
```

If I press "Button 1" I expect x=1, and DB= 'database001' is returned for the rest of the code by selDB funtion. I expect to see this in output of last print function:
`database is: database001`
but instead I get this crap:
`database is: <function selDB at 0x000002A736308DC8>`

What can be the problem?
Thank you guys in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. The crap can be seen because you are printing the function rather than invoking the function with arguments.

I would suggest to move the `print` statement inside the `selDB` function as you are invoking them with each button click.

```
def selDB (x):
    DB = None
    if x==1:
        print('database is: database 1')
        DB = 'database001'
    else:
        print('database is: database 2')
        DB= 'database002'
    root.destroy()
    return DB #makes no sense as this return value is not being used or stored anywhere
```

**EDIT**

Since you need to access the DB name for the rest of the program, you need to also add a global variable or use a class variable (if you are using a class), as follows:

```
DB = None # define the global variable DB
def selDB (x):
    global DB
    if x==1:
        print('database is: database 1')
        DB = 'database001'
    else:
        print('database is: database 2')
        DB= 'database002'
    root.destroy() # why do you want to destroy root? delete if not needed
    return
```

Now the database name will be stored in `DB` and can be accessed throughout your program

Another tip, do not use the following:

`button_1 = Button(root, text='database 1', command=lambda :selDB(1)) .pack()`.

In this case `button1` holds `None`. Rather do the following:

```
button_1 = Button(root, text='database 1', command=lambda :selDB(1))
button1.pack()
```

Now `button1` holds the reference to the `Button` widget created

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am a noob here, but It seems function doenst work in a usual way with tkinter: If I press "Button 1" I expect x=1, and DB= 'database001' is returned for the rest of the code. but the way I write the code, the tkinter and function is interconnected in a wrong way.
Unfortunatelly I cannot use the suggested code. The last print command represnets few hundred lines of code. I need the database name for the rest of the code, which is already developed. So I want to select a database by button and proceed the rest of the code with the selected database.

Comment: Many good tips, thanks! now works! Another lesson learnt: global should be defined inside the func, if defined outside it would not work!